# How to Migrate complete subversion setup from one Server to another with version upgrade

Tags: svn

I am very new to SVN and we would need your advise on below  query.

Currently we are using SVN 2.7.14 in our production environment and its hosted in windows server 2008R2. 
We are using this for Dcument management purpose and its having huge amount of data.
We have  a lot of scripts are running in svn servers like, pre&post commit hooks, and some scripts for copying automatically to some detination folders etc.

Now we are in a process to migrate the server from 2008R2 to 2012 or 2016. So we have below queries on the same.

1) What version of SVN we can chose for 2012 environment and if its 2016 what version of svn will support ?

2) What are the prerequiite we have to take care before migration.

3) Could you please share a step by step guide for the same

Regards
VOwner

Comment: Hi Team, Any suggestion here?

Comment: Please add your comments if you ever got a chance for migration